# Setting Client Credentials in VSTO

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, vsto

I'm trying to implement authentication using VSTO. I've added a web service reference which points to the WSDL below and it's generated all the classes necessary, however I can't find a class for the authentication, even though this is specified in the WSDL. I've tried editing the app.config file to make:

```
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
```

however, I still can't seem to get VS to generate the authentication classes which it should have auto-generated. Am I going about this the right way? Another option I searched was to create a SOAP extension. As all that really needs to happen is for the header to contain this authentication information:

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Created>2014-01-05T22:25:10.334Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2014-01-06T15:05:10.334Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>

    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>MyUserName</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MyPassword</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">MyNonce==</wsse:Nonce>

    <wsu:Created>2014-01-05T22:25:10.334Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s0:definitions xmlns:s1="http://rsm.govt.nz/smart/download" xmlns:s2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="DownloadService" targetNamespace="http://rsm.govt.nz/smart/download" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UTOverTransport">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:TransportToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false" />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic256 />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <sp:Layout>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Lax />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:TransportBinding>
        <sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <s0:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://rsm.govt.nz/smart/download" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://rsm.govt.nz/smart/download" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:include schemaLocation="DownloadLicences?xsd=LicenceDownloadService.xsd" />
    </xs:schema>
  </s0:types>
  <s0:message name="LicenceDownloadException">
    <s0:part name="errorMessage" element="s1:errorMessage" />
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="msgDetailResponse">
    <s0:part name="detailResponse" element="s1:Licence" />
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="msgSearchResponse">
    <s0:part name="searchResponse" element="s1:SearchResult" />
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="msgSearch">
    <s0:part name="arg0" element="s1:SearchCriteria" />
  </s0:message>
  <s0:message name="msgDetail">
    <s0:part name="arg0" element="s1:LicenceDetailsRequest" />
  </s0:message>
  <s0:portType name="LicenceDownloadWebService">
    <s0:operation name="searchLicences">
      <s0:input message="s1:msgSearch" />
      <s0:output message="s1:msgSearchResponse" />
      <s0:fault name="licenceDownloadException" message="s1:LicenceDownloadException" />
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="getLicenceDetails">
      <s0:input message="s1:msgDetail" />
      <s0:output message="s1:msgDetailResponse" />
      <s0:fault name="licenceDownloadException" message="s1:LicenceDownloadException" />
    </s0:operation>
  </s0:portType>
  <s0:binding name="LicenceDownloadServiceBinding" type="s1:LicenceDownloadWebService">
    <s2:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <s0:operation name="getLicenceDetails">
      <s2:operation soapAction="getLicenceDetails" style="document" />
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body use="literal" />
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body use="literal" />
      </s0:output>
      <s0:fault name="licenceDownloadException">
        <s2:fault use="literal" name="licenceDownloadException" namespace="" />
      </s0:fault>
    </s0:operation>
    <s0:operation name="searchLicences">
      <s2:operation soapAction="searchLicences" style="document" />
      <s0:input>
        <s2:body use="literal" />
      </s0:input>
      <s0:output>
        <s2:body use="literal" />
      </s0:output>
      <s0:fault name="licenceDownloadException">
        <s2:fault use="literal" name="licenceDownloadException" namespace="" />
      </s0:fault>
    </s0:operation>
  </s0:binding>
  <s0:service name="LicenceDownloadService">
    <s0:port name="LicenceDownloadServicePort" binding="s1:LicenceDownloadServiceBinding">
      <s2:address location="https://data.eat.business.govt.nz/services/DownloadLicences" />
    </s0:port>
  </s0:service>
</s0:definitions>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

I'll have a talk to the WSDL provider. I expected all the authentication information was included in the WSDL already from what I could see from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s0:definitions xmlns:s1="http://rsm.govt.nz/smart/download" xmlns:s2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="DownloadService" targetNamespace="http://rsm.govt.nz/smart/download" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UTOverTransport">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:TransportToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false" />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic256 />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <sp:Layout>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Lax />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:TransportBinding>
        <sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <s0:types>
```

I can also be sure that there is a header in each SOAP request as using SOAP UI the SOAP message raw looks like this:

```
POST https://data.eat.business.govt.nz/services/DownloadLicences?wsdl HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "searchLicences"
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: data.eat.business.govt.nz
Content-Length: 1219

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dow="http://rsm.govt.nz/smart/download" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>


    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-2" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsu:Created>2014-01-05T22:25:10.334Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2014-01-06T15:05:10.334Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>

        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>MyUserName</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MyPassword</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">MyNonce==</wsse:Nonce>

        <wsu:Created>2014-01-05T22:25:10.334Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>

   <soapenv:Body>
      <dow:SearchCriteria clientId="506682">
      </dow:SearchCriteria>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Kind Regards

Evan

Answer (score 0):

```
<s0:binding name="LicenceDownloadServiceBinding" type="s1:LicenceDownloadWebService">
<s2:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
<s0:operation name="getLicenceDetails">
  <s2:operation soapAction="getLicenceDetails" style="document" />
  <s0:input>
    <s2:body use="literal" />
  </s0:input>
  <s0:output>
    <s2:body use="literal" />
  </s0:output>
  <s0:fault name="licenceDownloadException">
    <s2:fault use="literal" name="licenceDownloadException" namespace="" />
  </s0:fault>
</s0:operation>
<s0:operation name="searchLicences">
  <s2:operation soapAction="searchLicences" style="document" />
  <s0:input>
    <s2:body use="literal" />
  </s0:input>
  <s0:output>
    <s2:body use="literal" />
  </s0:output>
  <s0:fault name="licenceDownloadException">
    <s2:fault use="literal" name="licenceDownloadException" namespace="" />
  </s0:fault>
</s0:operation>
```

Above is your wsdl bindings, I am not able to see any operation here, responsible for authentication. That's why it's not generating your required class, i guess. 
Ask your wsdl provider to implement authentication method which is required by you and regenerate wsdl..

**Updated:**

```
The authentication information e.g. username, password etc. are all included within   the header of each SOAP method. Which means when I send a "searchLicences" or "getLicenceDetails" message it will include the authentication details within the header of those messages
```

How are you so sure about header of soap message because as per your wsdl there is no soap header will come in your request.

```
<s2:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
<s0:operation name="getLicenceDetails">
<s2:operation soapAction="getLicenceDetails" style="document" />
  <s0:input>
    <s2:body use="literal" />
  </s0:input>
  <s0:output>
    <s2:body use="literal" />
  </s0:output>
 <s0:fault name="licenceDownloadException">
   <s2:fault use="literal" name="licenceDownloadException" namespace="" />
 </s0:fault>
</s0:operation>
```

If there would be a header in your incoming soap request it would be something like this.

```
 <s2:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
<s0:operation name="getLicenceDetails">
<s2:operation soapAction="getLicenceDetails" style="document" />
  <s0:input>
    <s2:body use="literal" />
    <s2:header message="tns:getAuthHeader" part="username" use="literal" /> 
    <s2:header message="tns:getAuthHeader" part="password" use="literal" /> 
  </s0:input>
  <s0:output>
    <s2:body use="literal" />
  </s0:output>
 <s0:fault name="licenceDownloadException">
   <s2:fault use="literal" name="licenceDownloadException" namespace="" />
 </s0:fault>
</s0:operation>
```

There is one more thing, sometimes webservice provider hide few methods like authentication in wsdl. You should consult your wsdl provider to include that method in your wsdl. Otherwise you won't able to generate that class in your client.

Comment: Hi user3090039, apologies I didn't state this more clearly. The authentication information e.g. username, password etc. are all included within the header of each SOAP method. Which means when I send a "searchLicences" or "getLicenceDetails" message it will include the authentication details within the header of those messages. So I don't think creating an authentication method would fix that unless I'm on the wrong track. Cheers for the input.

Comment: I'll have a talk to the WSDL provider. I expected all the authentication information was included in the WSDL already from what I could see from:

Comment: Also, have added an edit to my first post regarding the SOAP header authentication. That's why I thought it wouldn't be necessary to create a separate method for the authentication if it was already included within the header of another request.